# No content in TabNavigator

Tags: react-native

What could be the reason that content in Tab is not displayed?

I Receive a blank white box.

When I have only `export const TopNavTabs` without the `class App` it works but I need this as a component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Platform, View } from 'react-native'
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

import General from './components/tabs/General'
import Help from './components/tabs/Help'
import Tips from './components/tabs/Tips'

export const TopNavTabs = TabNavigator({
  General: { screen: General },
  Help: { screen: Help },
  Tips: { screen: Tips },
},
{
  animationEnabled:true
});

export default class App extends Component{

  render(){
      return(
          <View>
            <TopNavTabs />
          </View>
      )
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <App />
      );
    }
  }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => Test);
```

Comment: How are you using `App`? Are you using it in `index.js`? Can you show that?

Comment: @Li357 I added `index.js`

Comment: @Li357 If `<TopNavTabs />` I use without `<View>` tags, it works, but that's not the case. I want to have it as a component to be able to add a bar with other buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Maybe add flex to TopNavTabs?